# Why is this HTTP request so slow?

Tags: python, json, performance, http, request

Although the following code retrieves my gpa from the school's website I can't help but wonder if there is a faster way of doing this than the following code:

```
import requests, json

login_url = "https://www.uml.edu/sso/Auth/Login?returnUrl=/student-dashboard"
url = "https://www.uml.edu/student-dashboard/api/Enrollment/Classes?term=2530&career=1"

email = raw_input("Enter School Email: ")
passwd = raw_input("Enter Email Password: ")

payload = {"EmailAddress" : email,
       "Password" : passwd}

s = requests.Session()
s.post(login_url, data=payload)
r = requests.get(url, auth=(email, passwd))

result = json.loads(r.content)
print result.get('data').get('CareerCumulativeGpa')
```

Comment: Doesn't look like there should be anything particularly heavy here... Maybe the school's server is just slow..?

Comment: That's what I assumed but when I just go directly through the schools website it's pretty fast whereas this code takes a good 8-10 seconds to start up for some reason

Comment: Try to put some profiling code around the calls, see which ones take most of the time... Also, when you surf the site - is it making the same calls to the same endpoints?

Comment: Any reason why're "logging in", but still passing in BasicAuth data? Also, in your browser, try via "incognito mode" - might be something slow with the auth, and your browser has an active session when you load it up.

Comment: What would be the better way of the Auth? I'm really new to it and I thought this was the correct time to pass it.